# Entity Framework Migrations seeds duplicate rows

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I've got two classes

```
public class Category
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public sting Name { get; set; }
  public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

I have EF Migrations and the following seed:

```
var instockCategory = new Category() { Name = "InStock" };
var outofStockCategory = new Category() { Name = "OutOfStock" };

context.Items.AddOrUpdate(
 d => d.Name,
 new Item() { Name = "Item1", Category = instockCategory },
 new Item() { Name = "Item2", Category = outofStockCategory },
 new Item() { Name = "Item3", Category = outofStockCategory }
);
```

The line "d => d.Name" makes sure that based  on the name of the item, there won't be duplicate records when I reseed the database.
However, the first time I execute this, two categories are created with id 1 and 2. But the second time I run this, 3 new categories are created!
Can I fix this without manually adding every single category first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `AddOrUpdate` for your categories too.

```
var instockCategory = default(Category);
var outofStockCategory = default(Category);

context.Set<Category>().AddOrUpdate(
    c => c.Name,
    instockCategory = new Category() { Name = "InStock" },
    outofStockCategory = new Category() { Name = "OutOfStock" }
);

context.Items.AddOrUpdate(
    d => d.Name,
    new Item() { Name = "Item1", Category = instockCategory },
    new Item() { Name = "Item2", Category = outofStockCategory },
    new Item() { Name = "Item3", Category = outofStockCategory }
);
```

An explicit `DbSet` on your Context class is not necessary.

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Probably, but I don't want to, because then I'd have to add a Categories DbSet and for now I don't have it. Can still do it, just asking if something else was possible.

Comment: @DennisvanderStelt does the updated answer help? What exactly do you mean with "add a Categories DbSet"?